# Why do arrows point towards the codomain in function diagrams?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

The definition of a function given in Kenneth Rosen's Discrete Math Book is

> Let A and B be nonempty sets. A function from A to B is an **assingment of** exactly one element of B to each element of A. [Emphasis mine]

It seems the author wants us to think of the elements in the codomain being assigned to the elements in the domain, not the elements in the domain being assigned to the ones in the codomain. However, in this book and most others, functions are often illustrated with such diagrams:

[image]

If it is more useful to think of the elemnts in the codomain as **assigned to** the elements in the domain, is there a reason why the arrows are not pointing in the other direction?

Comment: If the domain is on the left, that diagram is not actually a function. Perhaps you'll find Rosen's description clearer if rearranged as follows: "A function from A to B is an assignment to each element of A of exactly one element of B." The mental picture is that from each element of A we draw one and only one one arrow emanating from it and pointing to some element of B (but multiple arrows may end up pointing to the same element of B).

Comment: @Rahul Oops my mistake, I changed the picture. Anyway, my question is why are the arrows emanating from the domain to the codomain, and not the other way around. If the elements of codomain are being assigned to the elements in the domain, shouldn't the arrows be pointing to the domain?

Comment: The more common way to think about it is that a function *maps* elements in the domain to values in the codomain i.e. $f : A \to B \,\mid\,a \mapsto f(a)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several different metaphors for functions that seem to be colliding here.  For example:

1. A function is a "machine" that takes an "input" and produces an "output"
2. A function is a "mapping" that takes an "input" and sends it to an "output"
3. A function is an "assignment" of a value to each element in the domain

The first two metaphors are most naturally thought of in terms of going *from* the element in the domain *to* the element in the codomain.  I agree with you that the third metaphor is most naturally thought of in the other direction.  Notice, though, how similar the following descriptions are, and how subtly the sense of "directionality" shifts:

- "An element of $B$ is assigned to each element of $A$"
- "To each element of $A$, we assign an element of $B$"
- "To each element of $A$ there corresponds an element of $B$"
- "Each element of $A$ is 'transformed' by the function into an element of $B$"

Answer (score 1):

I would say that this is more about conventions than mathematics. As long as the mathematical meaning is clear, what is the big deal?

For instance, in literature, the open interval $(a,b)$ can be also denoted as $]a,b[$. Arguing which notation is more reasonable is really not a mathematical question.

Answer (score 1):

The ideia is that *each* element of $A$ is associated to *one, and only one,* element of $B$.

If you didn't have "*each*", than you could have elements of $A$ that are not associated to anything in $B$.

If you didn't had " *one, and only one* " you could have a multivalued relation, as if $f(a) $ could mean more than one element of $B$. The way the your text express it is just a rephrasing of this ideia.